# Monster haunting a house near a lake

Tags: story-identification, horror

I am searching for a vivid horror story which is very similar to Algernon Blackwoods style. I read that as a adolescent in the 80s: The protagonist enters a house and realizes that something abominable and unnatural (it is *one* entity) is in the area (It is not ghosts like the Algernon Blackwood story with the remote island and the indians in the canoo).

One of the key scene was that the protagonist feels an irresistible urge to look out of the window when he exactly knew that he should not do that and his head slowly inches towards the window. It had a German title which was like "The house at the lake", I do not know the correct English name.

Comment: when were you an adolescent?

Comment: Oh geez, I didn't know there were that many books called "Das Haus am See". Giving up, sorry.

Comment: There is a sshort story called ["The Summer-House on the Lake"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1345826) by [John Edgell](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?123949) in his 1970 collection [*John Edgell's Ghosts*](http://www.amazon.com/John-Edgells-ghosts-omnibus-supernatural/dp/0853400202). Haven't seen it, no idea what it's about, or if it was ever translated into German.

Comment: @user14111 Unfortunately there is absolute not a single thing about the title in the internet. No abstract, no synopsis, nothing :-(. If someone has the story, it would be nice if he/she looks it up and tell if it fits the description.

Comment: I'm sure my suggestion was wrong. If the story you read was translated from English to German, it can't be so very obscure. That was just the only story in the ISFDB with "house" and "lake" in the title. I couldn't try all possible synonyms like "cottage by the pond" or "dwelling by the loch". And of course the English title could be completely different.

Comment: @user14111 Edgell's Ghosts is now available on Archive.org. Doesn't fit the description at all. Story is about a mother and daughter visiting their lake house after loss of father and son during WWII and the mother seeing them as ghosts calling her to an island on the lake.